# automatically move email from inbox to folder after certain time

Tags: email, gmail, email-filter, rules, hotmail

I have over 50 rules which automatically move incoming email (in both gmail and hotmail) when they arrive into folders. But the problem I have found is now I have to go through each folder to see if it has a new email.

So how do you create rules to automatically move email from inbox to a certain folder after certain time (say 1 week) or after they have been read.

Comment: Did you get the solution? People seems to have done something [similar](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2cca33d376f7f924fdaa67891ad098cc).

Comment: No I havent have the solution yet. Have you tried the script that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using operators.

**Example:**

```
category:primary in:inbox older_than:14d is:unread
```

[image]

**Step-by-step**

1. Open Gmail.
2. In the search box at the top, click Show search options.
3. Enter your search criteria. If you want to check that your search worked correctly, see what emails show up by clicking **Search**.
4. At the bottom of the search window, click **Create filter**.
5. Choose what you’d like the filter to do.
6. Click **Create filter**.

**For more details:** https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en

Comment: Please add enough details so that we do t have to look at the link to verify it